# Nested stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am new to SQL sever. Can anyone help me out on how to write a nested stored procedure in sql server 2008 that has ***output parameters***?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please keep in mind that we're not a code-writing service -- instead, we're a place to help you with your code. If you edit your post (click the "edit" button in the lower-left of your question) and include what you've already tried, you'll get a better reception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check this: [Nesting Stored Procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190607(v=sql.105).aspx) Although an important note to quote

> Although the nesting limit is 32 levels, SQL Server has no limit on
>   the number of stored procedures that can be invoked from a given
>   stored procedure, provided that the subordinate stored procedures do
>   not invoke other subordinate stored procedures and the maximum nesting
>   level is never exceeded.

**Example:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]
        @ID INT,
        @Emp INT

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @x UserDefinedTableVariable

    EXEC @x = Test2
        @SomeID = @ID

END
```